# Set image src and location to mouse on mouse over/enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list I'm building dynamically and want to show an image on mouse enter/over of the related list item.

OnmouseOver seems to fire multiple times and the src property does change but the image doesn't show in the browser.

This is what I currently have.

```
function showImage(e, src) {
    $("#imageContainer").css("left", e.pageX);
    $("#imageContainer").css("top", e.pageY);
    $("#imageContainer").show();
    $("#itemImage").attr("src", src);
}

function hideImage() {
    $("#imageContainer").hide();
    $("#itemImage").attr("src", "");
}

@foreach (var item in Model.items)
{
    string imageUrl = "test.com/images/"+ item.ImageName;

    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" onmouseover="showImage(event, @imageUrl)" onmouseout="hideImage()">@item.Name</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

<div id="imageContainer" style="display: none; position: absolute;"> 
    <img class="itemImage" src="#" />
</div>
```

Comment: you have display:none in your image style attribute. remove that to let the image be shown.

Comment: display : none affects all child elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `id` selector for '`itemImage`' which is actually a `class`.You need to use class selector.

Change :

```
$("#itemImage").attr("src", src);
$("#itemImage").attr("src", "");
```

to

```
$(".itemImage").attr("src", src);
$(".itemImage").attr("src", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `display:none position: absolute` after you assign the src attribute.

use this:

```
$("#itemImage").removeAttr("style");
```